# Authorize issue in MVC - database used flat file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC. I am facing below problem.
I wrote all logic in model.In Web.config I mention path of file (No Connection string).

I am adding `[Authorize]` attribute. After login, it is navigating to Home page. When I navigate gift create page again redirect to login page (Recursive).

FYI: Temporarily I am using session variable to solve problem.

This is my code

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Create")]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult CreateGift(GiftModel gif)
    {
        if (Session["UserType"] != null)
        {
            if (Session["UserType"].ToString() == "1")
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "home");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
        }
        string path = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Path"];
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Gift InsertCoupon = new Gift(path);

            InsertCoupon.InsertGift(gif);
            return RedirectToAction("GiftList");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

In Web.config

```
<add key="Path" value="D:\"/>
```

Login Page

```
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel user)
    {
        string path = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Path"];
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        { 
        Users LoginUser = new Users(path);
        UserModel uM = new UserModel();
        uM.Password = user.Password;
        uM.User_Email_ID = user.User_Email_ID;
        uM.Name = user.Name;
        string res = LoginUser.LoginUser(uM);
        uM = LoginUser.GetUserFrom_Email(user.User_Email_ID);
        if (res != "")
            ViewBag.Msg = res;
        else
        {
            Session["username"] = uM.Name;
            Session["E_Mail"] = uM.User_Email_ID;
            Session["UserType"] = uM.User_Type;
            if (uM.User_Type == 0)
                return RedirectToAction("AdminHome", "Admin");
            else
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: what is the issue here?

Comment: exactly, what is the issue ? please elaborate ..

Comment: Data store in XML file (DML command) operation handled in model layer. I am getting user information from model. I am try to use "Authorize" attribute to validate user. When add [Authorize] it's keep on asking for login.